# How to get a value in XML file by the ID using VBScript?

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have the following XML file:

```xml
<TOOLING>
  <TOOLENVIRONMENT>         
    <TOOL>
      <TOOLSNAME>MyABCVersion1</TOOLSNAME>
      <TOOLSVERSION>12.34.56</TOOLSVERSION>
    </TOOL>  

    <TOOL>
      <TOOLSNAME>MyABCVersion2</TOOLSNAME>
      <TOOLSVERSION>23.45.67</TOOLSVERSION>
    </TOOL> 

    <TOOL>
      <TOOLSNAME>MyABCVersion3</TOOLSNAME>
      <TOOLSVERSION>34.56.78</TOOLSVERSION>
    </TOOL>                      
  </TOOLENVIRONMENT>
</TOOLING>
```

I wanted to get the value of `<TOOLS_VERSION>` from XML file by using the `<TOOLS_NAME>`. Which means I want to search in XML file for "MyABCVersion1" and retrieve the value "12.34.56". After retrieving I wanted to replace the version name with the new version name which will be provided in the parameters.

I have tried the script like the following by taking the first tag of the file, but in future if the order changes that will not work:

```vb
Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXMLDoc.Async = False
objXMLDoc.Load("autorun.xml")
WScript.Echo objXMLDoc.Xml

Set ElemList = objXMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName("TOOLSNAME")
plot = ElemList.item(0).Text
WScript.Echo plot

Set ElemList = objXMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("TOOLSNAME")
plot = ElemList.Item(1).Text
WScript.Echo plot
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is best done with an [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) expression. Also, `Microsoft.XMLDOM` is deprecated. Use `Msxml2.DOMDocument` instead.

```vb
Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
objXMLDoc.Async = False
objXMLDoc.Load("autorun.xml")
xpath = "//TOOL[./TOOLS_NAME/text()='MyABCVersion1']/TOOLS_VERSION"
Set node = objXMLDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath)
node.Text = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ansgar, it worked for me. I wanted to replace the version name with new version name which will be provided in the parameters. For that I have used the syntax: Replace(strText, "OldValue", Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)). But it does not work for me. How can I replace here ?

Comment: `Replace` doesn't work in-place. You need to assign the new or modified value back to the node.

Comment: If I need to assign the new value to the node, how can I perform that.? Because I am bit confused.,Can you please clarify.

Comment: I already did. Please re-read my answer.

Comment: Sorry. Thank you so much. It works for me.

Comment: @Dinesh so you're not [Manikandan R C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10411356/manikandan-r-c) the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52735729/692942) looked pretty similar until you deleted it.

Comment: I am not getting you, and I am not that person.